# garage vapor barrier

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I am converting my garage into a wood shop and have insulated my walls with faced R13 insulation.The ceilings have faced R13 installed with R30 unfaced additional to the R13. Do I need to install plastic sheathing on the ceiling. I plan on installing 7/16 OSB sheathing on the walls and ceiling.

Comment: Is your garage a separate structure or attached to your home?

Comment: Attached garage

Comment: You may want to check the local building code regarding fire resistant wall coverings in an attached garage. It doesn't matter what you use it for, if it has a garage door it is considered a garage in most localities.